# How do I make sure the children being passed into component are of a certain type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I'm having some trouble in typing the `children` prop so that I can't receive elements that aren't of that type.

Here's the example with the components that I'm using:

The parent component:

```js
type DropdownProps = {
 children: ?
};

export const Dropdown: React.FC<DropdownProps> = ({
  children,
}) => {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown">
        <ul className="dropdown-list">
          {children}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

The items:

```js
type DropdownItemProps = {
  Icon?: React.FC<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  text: string;
  hideDropdown: () => void;
};

export const DropdownItem: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<DropdownItemProps>> = ({
  children,
  Icon,
  text,
  hideDropdown,
}) => {
  if (children) {
    return (
      <li onClick={hideDropdown} className="dropdown-item">
        {children}
      </li>
    );
  }
  return (
    <li className="dropdown-item" onClick={hideDropdown}>
      <div className="dropdown-item-child-group">
        {Icon && <Icon className="dropdown-item__icon" />}
        <span>{text}</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

```js
type DropdownLinkItemProps = {
  toPath: string;
} & DropdownItemProps;

export const DropdownLinkItem: React.FC<DropdownLinkItemProps> = ({
  text,
  Icon,
  toPath,
  hideDropdown,
}) => {
  return (
    <li className="dropdown-item" onClick={hideDropdown}>
      <NavLink className="dropdown-item-child-group dropdown-link" to={toPath}>
        {Icon && <Icon className="dropdown-item__icon" />}
        <span>{text}</span>
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  );
};
```

I want the children of `Dropdown` to be an array of of either `DropdownItem` or `DropdownLinkItem`.

I've tried using `React.FC<DropdownItemProps | DropdownLinkItemProps>` but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: i'm afraid that this is not possible right now

Comment: You can't. An instance of a React component is just `JSX.Element`, no information of the original class/function is preserved. `React.FC<DropdownItemProps | DropdownLinkItemProps>` does not work either because that would be the class/function type, not the type of an _instance_ of that class/function. There is no way to do it without circumventing natural JSX which is messy and not at all advisable.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks anyways.